# Entity Framework deployment issue

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5, odp.net

I have developed a WCF SOAP web service, let's call it Project W, hosted on a Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.5

Project W depends, for its data access logic, on a class library project, let's call it Project E, that makes use of Entity Framework 6 to access two database servers (one Oracle 10g and a SQL server 2008).

I have added Entity Framework 6 and the related Oracle 12c provider to Project E with the nu-get package manager. Everything seems fine and I can see all necessary .dll referenced in the Project E references. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll both have the "Copy local" property set to true and are effectively copied to the bin directory of my development machine.

However, when I publish (with "file system" method) the entire solution to the production server the above .dll don't get copied. Which is the reccomended approach to get the above .dll published along the others?

Comment: It is probably related to this?: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2352

Comment: Yes thanks. I have solved the issue a while ago adopting strategy #1 described in the provided link